how to use spl_associated_token_account in solana_porgram_test?
experiencing error: linking with cc failed: exit status: 1, when I am running  ProgramTestContext , like I want to createATAinstruction so that I should have the data in the ata that shows it exists
that is why I am using this
    use spl_associated_token_account::get_associated_token_address;

but I am unable to do in my test cases of rust, need help.

There's not enough information provided in the question, but I'm guessing that you're declaring a dependency on spl-associated-token-account like this in your Cargo.toml:
spl-associated-token-account = "VERSION_STRING"

This means that your program likely has two separate entrypoints defined, which causes build errors. To get around that, you should import the ATA crate with the no-entrypoint feature, ie:
spl-associated-token-account = { version = "VERSION_STRING", features = ["no-entrypoint"] }

Separately, there's a new much lighter client crate which just has the instruction creators and address derivation functions: https://crates.io/crates/spl-associated-token-account-client
